# Primefaces: limit scope of global tooltip

Tags: primefaces, tooltip, primefaces-extensions

Is there a way to define a scope for a global tooltip? I would like to use a PF tooltip only for the children of a component. I have seen primefaces extension have an extended version of the tooltip, but I can't find an example for my particular case.

Comment: do you mean a scope for a template tooltip (that you have to use in many pages) ???

Comment: I mean that the PF tooltip should not be used for the whole table (replacing default tooltip), instead it should only be only active within a component (for example a <table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using attribute globalSelector="..." on can limit the use of the tooltip fot certains elements(for example globalSelector="a")